# Disable fullscreen keyboard in landscape mode?

Tags: keyboard

Do we have any solution for this, ***without rooting*** the phone?

I've seen videos from 6 years back when people are hunting for this.

Now in 2021, in the time of foldables, it's pretty awkward having a fullscreen keyboard on a *1768 x 2208* pixel screen (ok, more frankly, on a *2208 x 1768*)

Please let me know if you are aware of anything.

I'm specifically searching the disabling option for Samsung Keyboard, if that matters, or making it more easy by any chance.

Thanks.

Comment: use bluetoooth keyboard

Comment: Blah. Or use Windows, right?

Comment: once bluetooth keyboard is added, there is notification menu where you select favorite keyboard (same if multiple keyboard apps installed). every time you want to hide keyboard, select the bluetooooth keyboard

Comment: @alecxs: you don't get my point. I don't want to hide the keyboard. I just don't want it to go to fullscreen. When I reply to a message on let's say WhatsUp: portrait mode is fine, but in landscape keyboard takes the whole screen, and I can't see who am I writing to.

Comment: try gboard one hand mode or use transparent keyboard theme https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB5kS.jpg

Comment: "I'm specifically searching the disabling option for Samsung Keyboard"

Comment: samsung keyboard app is "disabled" when another app is used. There are plenty much apps on google play. if your question is about feature request for samsung keyboard app, this is the wrong place for support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the point of fullscreen keyboard on Android?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125959/what-is-the-point-of-fullscreen-keyboard-on-android)

Comment: Can you please try another keyboard and report back it's issue with keyboards like Samsung keyboard or with apps like WhatsApp? I don't use WhatsApp or other facebook apps

Comment: This is the issue with the apps. In other apps it works great (Gmail, youtube search, etc).

Comment: Then I doubt there is any disabling option for Samsung Keyboard

Comment: From app developer's viewpoint it's as easy as this: `<EditText android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen">`. With XPosed, it bans the keyboard's evaluation if the app is in fullscreen or not, and pretend that it's not.